# Aomei backupper and backup speed

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, backup

I have a new pc with ssd and hdd on it. ssd has two partitions. one has win 11 and the other is for backup. I don't understand why Aomei backupper makes a much faster backup of windows on hdd (3 minutes) than on ssd second partition (5 minutes)
hdd is toshiba p300, 3T, 7200
ssd is adata XPG SX6000 Pro.
processor is i5 12400

I did tests with DiskMark and the ssd is about 3 times faster than the hdd, as it should be, so I'm curious why the backup is slower

thanks in advance

Comment: You're reading & writing to the same drive simultaneously. This, apart from being slow, is not a great way to plan your backup strategy. If the drive dies you lose the main & the backup at the same time.

Comment: thank you for your reply. 

Yes you're right about backup on same place as windows. however, I mostly make backups so that I don't have to reinstall windows due to various software problems that may occur over time or maybe viruses. I must say that in the more than last 20 years that I have been using computers, I have never had a hardware failure, so I did not take that into account.But you are right. Although, I also save some backups on the hdd, mainly because of the higher speed of backup process. So the slower speed on SSD is due to simultaneous reading and writing? Ok then.

Comment: You've been lucky so far. Out of only 4 computers in the house, one year I lost two boot drives to 'mechanical'/electronic failure, resulting in total loss of the drives - but, thanks to backup strategy, both machines were back up & running within the hour, once new drives were installed. Usually drives give enough warning that you can replace before total failure, but this seems less true for SSD than HD. All my HD failures have been 'slow' [though they are also backed up].